# Why Google Search bar and logo is not vertically center in large screen?

Tags: usability, google, alignment

Its comes to my mind when i do googling on a **large screen Desktop**. **the logo and search bar area is Horizontally Center (Near about, not so measurable)**

[image]

but **not Vertically Center in case of large screen**...

[image]

Is there any **Justified Reason** for it ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: The vertical position doesn't change if window size is changed, ie position is fixed. And from my CSS days, I remember vertical align, especially centering vertically was very hard but achievable with extraneous elements. Google likes to keep their search page minimal in size. So this is either about implementation, or only Google knows, which makes everything we say a guesswork.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned by @locationunknown in the comments, the vertical position doesn't change when the window is resized.

But to answer your question. I believe it is because **Google doesn't want you to travel visually far from the top of the screen.**

Most of the important information is in the top of the screen (highlighted with red). Tabs, address bar, profile settings, link to mail, extensions and etc. So making the most important (and only) part of the website fixed to the top makes sense.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I agree with what rojcyk and locationunknown said.

In addition to that, I think we've become accustomed to having our websites always start at top.  Horizontally, we are used to centered OR left justified, but centered vertically would be disorienting to some.

Also, it's always possible that they have never made a logical decision to NOT center it vertically, it's just how websites naturally lay themselves out.  You really gotta go out of your way to center it vertically